# Reason for $r (t)$ as a functional in path integral derivation of state-operator isomorphism in Polchinski

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral

While deriving state-operator isomorphism using path integral Polchinksi introduce us to eq $(2.8.18)$ $$\int_{}\mathcal{D\phi'_b}\mathcal{D}\phi_i \exp(-S[\phi_i])\color{red}{r^{-L_0-\tilde{L_o}}}\Psi[\phi'_b]$$
Here $\Psi[\phi_b']$ is an arbitrary state (Schrodinger representation) with a mentioned boundary condition of $\phi_b'$ on the inner circle of annular region.
First integration is done with all values of $\phi_i$ within the annular region while keeping $\phi_b$ (outer) and $\phi_b'$ (inner) fixed and in the last integration we take all value of $\phi_b'$

The boundary condition and field position looks like

[image]

The result of above integral is told to be $\Psi[\phi_b]$. I can't understand why we're using the term $\color{red}{r^{-L_0-\tilde{L_o}}}$ in path integral? It is acting as some sort of time evolution operator so it should have been of form $\exp{(-Ht)}$ (wick rotated) where $H\propto L_0+\tilde{L_o}$ and $t=|z|=r$.

Comment: The Weyl transformation from the plane to the cylinder shows that $t = \log r$.